# cordova-plugin-apprate on iOS 17+ devices - Error "Call must be made on main thread"

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ios17

## Environment

macOS Sonoma 14.0
Cordova 10.0.0
cordova ios 6.2
Xcode 15.0.1

Trying run app on "iPad(10th gen) 17.0.1"

## Issue

When my app runs `AppRate.navigateToAppStore();`, it crashes the app. It seems occur because it runs on another thread not the main thread on iOS devices. The error log is below:
[image: ipad_error]

On iOS 16 devices it still working fine, but on iOS 17+ not.
How could I change the thread that calls this function to the main thread?